# Action Script 3 draw in front of a movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drawing

I'm new flash and action script.
here is the problem.
i have created a simple application. and added just two items to the stage. a movie clip object and a button object. movie clip object has mouse event listeners set to draw on it. but when i draw, the lines are drawn behind the movie clip object (on the stage), i want to draw it on the object.
here is my code

```
var write: Boolean;

write = false;
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startWriting);
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, continueWriting);
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopWriting);
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopWriting);
btnHide.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, hideBoard);

var g:Graphics = graphics;
g.lineStyle(1, 0x0000ff);   

function startWriting(e:MouseEvent):void {
    g.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    write = true;
}

function continueWriting(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(write) {
        g.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

function stopWriting(e:MouseEvent):void {
    write = false;
}

function hideBoard(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (board.visible){
        board.visible = false;
    }
    else {
        board.visible = true;
    }
}
```

so the question is how do i draw on the movie clip object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each MovieClip have their own graphics property. The contents you added in are always in front of the current movieclip graphics.

The solution is just add a Shape as child of your MovieClip :

```
var shape : Shape = new Shape;
addChild( shape );
var g:Graphics = shape .graphics;
g.lineStyle(1, 0x0000ff);   

function startWriting(e:MouseEvent):void {
    g.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    write = true;
}

function continueWriting(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(write) {
        g.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```